# How can I get text dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, getboundingclientrect

This snippet gives the width of the "theDiv", which equals to the width of the page:

```
<div id="theDiv">This is some text</div>
<script>
    var rect = document.getElementById("theDiv").getBoundingClientRect();
    alert("width of text is (not): " + rect.width);
</script>
```

Is there any way to get the width (and height) of the actual text in the div?

note: I'm developing a chrome extension that analyzes web-pages - I cannot change the dom and the css, meaning I cannot use span instead of div or change the style of the element.

Comment: Can you use a canvas?

Comment: Can you add an element to the DOM if it's hidden, i.e. doesn't influence the visible page in any shape or form at all?

Comment: I can't modify the dom at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) to measure text.  For example:

```js
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById("theDiv"));
var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "width of text is: " + rect.width;
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">This is some text</div>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the dom then you could make `theDiv` `inline-block` via CSS:

```
#theDiv {
   display: inline-block
}
```

Ok, in this case you could create virtual element, append it to the dom, calculate dimensions and then remove it from dom:

```
// fetch source element and his content
var div = document.getElementById("theDiv"),
    text = div.innerHTML;

// create virtual span to calculate dimestions
var span = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
    span.innerHTML = text,
    rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();

alert(rect.width);

// remove virtual span from the DOM
document.body.removeChild(span);
```

Comment: sorry, I extended my note: I cannot change the css file either.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an element's text's width by itself isn't possible without the use of an extra (inline, usually invisible) element, as far as I know, or could tell.
For those others who arrive here without OP's restrictions though, it is possible using only JS and without affecting the page's flow at all.

```
var target = ... // Whichever element's text's width you wish to measure
var ruler = document.createElement("span");

ruler.style.position = "absolute"; // remove from the page's flow
ruler.style.visibility = "hidden"; // and totally stop it from being rendered

// copy font-size, font-family and the text itself
ruler.style.fontSize = target.style.fontSize;
ruler.style.fontFamily = target.style.fontFamily;
ruler.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;

// add to the document so that the styles get applied, allowing us to discover its width
document.body.appendChild(ruler);
var textWidth = ruler.offsetWidth;
// and then promptly remove again from the document
document.body.removeChild(ruler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use clientWidth or offsetWidth

```
Use var offsetWidth =element.offsetWidth;
```

the difference is offsetWidth includes border width, clientWidth does not

[image]